# Function drops invalid values in dataframes but then it returns original dataframes with invalid values

Tags: python, pandas

I created this simple function:

```
def cleanup_data(*argv):
    for df in argv:
        df = df.dropna()
    return argv
```

However, if I call cleanup_data(df1, df2), and later I do:

```
df1.isnull().values.any()
```

or

```
df2.isnull().values.any()
```

I get True.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the updated dataframes, but rather the unchanged `argv`. Here's how you could return a list of updated dataframes using a list comprehension:

```
def cleanup_data(*argv):
    return [df.dropna() for df in argv]
```

Alternatively you could make `df.dropna` operate in-place on the dataframes:

```
def cleanup_data(*argv):
    for df in argv:
        df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: But isn't each element in argv a soft copy of each df? Isn't df = df.dropna() the same as df.dropna(inplace=True) ?

Comment: @user By default `df.dropna` returns a copy, which you then assign to the variable `df`, but you never updated the original `argv` list with that copy.

Comment: Ok, but df in argv, so, I am changing df, isn't that changing argv? I never made a hard copy.

Comment: @user Assigning something new to the `df` variable does nothing at all to `argv`. If you want to edit `argv` while you loop over it you'll need to loop over `range(len(argv))`, and assign to `argv[i]` instead of `df`. Using a list comprehension is cleaner, however.

Comment: What I don't understand is, what is the difference between df=df.dropna() and df.dropna(inplace=True) ?

Comment: Using `inplace=True` edits the dataframe (that is stored in `argv`). The default (`inplace=False`) does not edit the dataframe that's in `argv`, but rather returns an edited copy.